# How to extract button events of default alert dialog using javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dialog, alert, addeventlistener

I am doing web development.
When you try to move from the current page to another page in the web browser, a notification window should pop up and the function should be called when the exit button is pressed, and the function should not be called when the stay button is pressed.
How to solve this problem?

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
    console.log('show alert dialog');
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = "Not Leave!";
    
    window.addEventListener("unload", function(event) {
        console.log('unload event');
        console.log(event);
        if (event.persisted || !event.currentTarget.closed) {
            console.log("User stayed on the page");
        } else {
            console.log("User left the page");
        }
    });
});
```

I used this code but got no results.
Also, the body text "Not Leave!" was not manifested as
How can i solve this problem?